# AngularJS check box upon clicking on input field

Tags: jquery, angularjs, checkbox, click, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following piece of code in my HTML page, with a very standard controller.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>Item ID</th>
        <th>1st Value</th>
        <th>2nd Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="(id, values) in myItemList">
        <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[id]">  {{id}}</td>
        <td> <input type="number" ng-model="values.first"></td>
        <td> <input type="number" ng-model="values.second"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In the above code an item is selected only when the checkbox is clicked. However, I would like that when the user clicks on either of the two numerical input fields of any particular row, the associated checkbox is checked.

I have not found anywhere a similar problem. Usually the problem that developer face is to make something happen when a checkbox is checked. However, this case is different.

I don't know how AngularJS can help me with this problem, considering that the rows are displayed through in a `ng-repeat` loop. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it this way :

HTML :

```
 <div ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="testController">
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>Item ID</th>
            <th>1st Value</th>
            <th>2nd Value</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="(id, values) in myItemList">
            <td> <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected[id]">  {{id}}</td>
            <td> <input type="number" ng-click="selectRow(id);" ng-model="values.first"></td>
            <td> <input type="number" ng-click="selectRow(id);" ng-model="values.second"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller code :

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);
app.controller('testController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myItemList = [{ first: 'aaa', second: 'bbbb' }, { first: 'aa1', second: 'bbb1' }, { first: 'aa2', second: 'bbb2' }];
    $scope.selected = [false, false, false];
    $scope.selectRow = function (id) {
        $scope.selected[id] = true;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ffxddsre/

As you can see, all I did is adding a selectRow function and bind it to the click event of the inputs, when the input is clicked it sets the corresponding selected flag and Angular's two way binding mechanism take care of updating the UI.

Comment: Of course, how could I not think about this? Very simple and clean solution, thank you!